# How to use a range defined by user input on multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I get workbooks with multiple tabs of identically formatted data but the exact ranges of the data varies between workbooks. Instead of modifying the code each time, I am trying to establish a user input that would define a reference range on one worksheet that can be applied to all the worksheets.  My problem is that the defined range keeps referring back to my "reference" range and not applying to the active worksheet. I am ending up with the same data being copied repeatedly.

```
Sub Copy_data()

Dim Destination_Rng As Range
Dim Header_Rng As Range
Dim Data_Rng As Range
Dim Label_Rng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim SheetName As String
Dim SheetExists As Boolean

On Error Resume Next


SheetName = InputBox("Please enter a name for your new sheet")
SheetExists = False
 
With ThisWorkbook
        'Check if the Sheet exists
        For Each ws In .Worksheets
            If ws.Name = SheetName Then
                SheetExists = True
                MsgBox ("Summary tab already exists - Ending Script")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
        
        If SheetExists = False Then
            'If the sheet dont exists, create
            .Worksheets.Add Sheets(1)
            ActiveSheet.Name = SheetName
        End If
End With


Sheets(2).Activate
'Get user input for data header
Set Header_Rng = Application.InputBox("Select by mouse or enter (e.g. A1:B2) the Header Data:", Type:=8)
'Get user input for data to be compiled
Set Data_Rng = Application.InputBox("Select by mouse or enter (e.g. A1:B2) the Data to be compiled:", Type:=8)
'Get user input for data label
Set Label_Rng = Application.InputBox("Select by mouse or enter (e.g. A1:B2) the data label:", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0

'Test to ensure User Did not cancel
  If Header_Rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  If Data_Rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  If Label_Rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  

Header_Rng.Copy
Sheets(SheetName).Activate
Range("B1").PasteSpecial
'sometimes the header is formatted weird so adding a value between header and data
Sheets(SheetName).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Value = "X"

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   If ws.Name <> SheetName Then
        Data_Rng.Copy
        Sheets(SheetName).Activate
        Set Destination_Rng = Sheets(SheetName).Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Destination_Rng.Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Label_Rng.Cells(1, 1).Copy
        Sheets(SheetName).Activate
        Destination_Rng.Offset(0, -1).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
Next ws
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Work with the `.Address` of the selected range.

Comment: Instead of `Label_Rng.Cells(1, 1).Copy` you'd do something like `ws.Range(Label_Rng.Cells(1, 1).Address).Copy`

Comment: `.address` after the defined range errors as an "invalid qualifier"

Comment: `ws.Range(Datal_Rng).Address).Copy` that was the trick!